# Do I need a special visa to work remotely in Spain

Tags: visas, schengen, spain, work, working-visas

I work full time (remote) as a software developer for an Australian country. I'm thinking of living in Spain for 3 - 6 months of the year and working remotely from there. Currently I don't need a visa to go to Spain on holidays for up to 3 months.

So I have 2 questions.

1. If I live in Spain for 3 months can I work from there remotely without a visa, if not what visa would I require?
2. If I live in Spain for 6 months working remotely what visa would I require?

Comment: It looks like Spain is currently in the process of creating a "digital nomad visa" program but that it has not yet done so.

Comment: The *Red Pueblos Acogedores* might be of interest https://pueblosacogedores.com/

Comment: According to this Nov 2021 report https://www.fragomen.com/insights/remote-work-in-the-european-union-back-to-the-feuture.html only 3 countries allow remote work as a primary purpose of stay: Estonia for migrant workers on Schengen Area employment contracts; and Latvia and Luxembourg for up to 90 days. The majority currently permit remote work for a few days, if incidental to a primary purpose of stay such as a business or private visit

Comment: @Traveller [This](https://expertvagabond.com/digital-nomad-work-visas/) April 2022 article suggests that there are 20+ countries where you can remote work.  Spain is listed there, but they point out that under the visa the article refers to, you are not allowed to work (this is not a digital nomad style of visa )

Comment: Unless something changed recently, you would have to get a Spanish national visa, not a Schengen tourist/business visa. In very general terms, a business visa allows you to talk about business, but not to do do the work. So this question belongs to Expatriates SE.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It looks like the Digital Nomad visa that will be part of the Start Up Act will be what I need. Hopefully it'll be in place by the time I'm ready to live in Spain.